# Importing pyopoenssl for Python 2.7 in Windows 64

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyopenssl

I need to use pyOpenSSL in my python code. I am trying to install the package using easy_install. I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\xxx>easy_install pyopenssl
Searching for pyopenssl
Best match: pyopenssl 16.2.0
Processing pyopenssl-16.2.0-py2.7.egg
pyopenssl 16.2.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyopenssl-16.2.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pyopenssl
Searching for cryptography>=1.3.4
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cryptography/
Best match: cryptography 1.7.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/82/f7/d6dfd7595910a20a563a83a762bf79a253c4df71759c3b228accb3d7e5e4/cryptography-1.7.1.tar.gz#md5=2f63dee6ace602d1d20d1995f8538015
Processing cryptography-1.7.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-7lajgq\cryptography-1.7.1\setup.cfg
Running cryptography-1.7.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-7lajgq\cryptography-1.7.1\egg-dist-tmp-shxong
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
_openssl.c
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_openssl.c(434) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command '"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you suggest how to solve it? Is there anything I need to install?

Comment: to my mind, in order to install a Python binding for OpenSSL, you should install a 'normal' C + asm version of OpenSSL first and only then try to build PyOpenSSL.